# Does this (shared) logic belong in Backbone Model or View or separate utility?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I am drawing a chart with icons that can vary in size (see image).

The **icon scale** in my Backbone View "A" is calculated based on a number of attributes in my chart model: availableWidth, availableHeight, yGranularity, xMax etc.

When the icon scale has been calculated I'd like this value to be available to both View A and View B (where B serves as a chart Legend).

**2 questions:**
1) In Backbone, where would be I place the "iconSizeCalculation" so that the calculated value is available to both views.

2) What is a good way of handling different "actions" in Backbone? Let's say View B should only respond when the aforementioned (calculated attribute) iconSize changes, whereas A should respond to changes in size, time, granularity etc. What I mean specifically by "action" is how I can differentiate single-attribute changes from multi-attribute changes and respond accordingly? (Should I count the properties in model.changedAttributes?)
(Or maybe this problem stems from not separating View/Controller-concerns in a proper manner?)

Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1) In Backbone, where would be I place the "iconSizeCalculation" so that the calculated value is available to both views.`

Backbone has a built in event system that will make this very easy. I'm going to assume you will have more than one item in your display, and that the legend will show the size of all of the items being displayed. Is that a fair assumption?

To set this up, I would have three separate view classes, all connected with events:

- A ChartView - which represents the entire chart
- An IconView - which represents individual icons to be displayed on the chart
- A LegendView - which represents the legends on the chart

The ChartView should receive a collection of Icon models. Once it receives this, it should loop through the list of Icons and instantiate / render / display an IconView for each Icon in the collection. It should also pass the entire collection along to the LegendView.

The LegendView should loop through the list of icons and render some text for each one, using a LegendIconView for each. The LegendIconView should listen to `change:size` events from the Icon models, so that it can know when the "size" of a model changes. The change event will tell you which Icon has been updated, so you can update the display of the legend accordingly.

`2) What is a good way of handling different "actions" in Backbone?`

When you bind to a `change` event in Backbone models and collections you can either bind to the generic `change` or to a specific attribute change. For example, if you have a `size` attribute, you can listen to the changes in size with: `change:size`. This works for both models and collections. When you listen to `change:size` in a model, it tells you that this attribute has changed for that model. When you listen to `change:size` in a collection, it tells you that the size for a model has changed. The event args also tell you which model has changed, in the collection handler.

---

Here's a rough idea of what your code may look like to handle your needs

```
Icon = Backbone.Model.extend({});
Icons = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Icon
});

ChartView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "renderIcon");
  },

  render: function(){
    var legendView = new LegendView({collection: this.collection});
    legendView.render();
    $(this.el).append(legendView.el);

    this.collection.each(this.renderIcon);
  },

  renderIcon: function(icon){
    var iconView = new IconView({model: icon});
    iconView.render();
    $(this.el).append(iconView.el);
  }
});

IconView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    // set up your events, to handle clicking, dragging, resizing, etc
  },

  render: function(){
    var html = // render some html here. jquery templates, mustache, or whatever
    $(this.el).html(html);
  }
});

LegendView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "renderIconLegend");
  },

  renderIconLegend: function(icon){
    var legendIconView = new LegendIconView({model: icon});
    legendIconView.render();
    $(this.el).append(legendIconView.el);
  },

  render: function(){
    this.collection.each(this.renderIconLegend);
  }
});

IconLegendView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model.bind("change:size", this.updateSize, this);
  },

  updateSize: function(model, newSize){
    var sizeEl = this.$(".sizeElement");
    sizeEl.text(newSize);
  },

  render: function(){
    var html = // render some html here
    $(this.el).html(html);
  }
});

var data = [{ /*some icon data*/ }, {/*more icon data*/}];
var icons = new Icons(data);
var chart = new ChartView({collection: icons});
chart.render();
$("#myChartElement").html(chart.el);
```

This should give you an idea of how all of this will work.

When an individual model has it's `size` attribute updated, the IconLegendView instance for that model will receive the change event, allowing you to update the display of the legend for that icon.

Comment: Big thanks for the detailed code. I'll have a thorough read-through. In my case, I only have a single Legend icon which should have the same scale as the icons drawn in another view. I'm not using Backbone models/views for the specific icons as these are drawn using d3.js. I basically only want to make sure that whenever any of 4 attributes (that affect iconSize) are changed in the model, both views should have access to the calculated result for further rendering using SVG rendering libraries ...!? Thanks for any further input :)

Comment: i think the events on the model are still going to be what you want. you'll be able to get notification of the values that are changing through them